# How do I stop Nautilus from popping-up a window when I attach a device (phone, USB, etc)?

Tags: nautilus

I just upgraded to Raring from 12.10 and there is an annoying new behavior. Everytime I attach a device, or worse, reboot my phone, Nautilus throws up a pop-up window with the filesystem contents. I do not mind automounting, in fact, usually I like it, but I really don't need nautilus to pop-up a window. I reboot my phone a lot when I'm working on it and so this is highly annoying.

Answer (score 6):

Go to: System Settings... > (System) Details > Removable Media

Select how media should be handled